# Multiple variables assigned to one variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know what kind of syntax the line below is called.

```
var that = {}, first, last;
```

Note: I found a post on this site about this question, but they said [ ] has to be added around the variables on the right handside to make it an array.  But the code below does work.

Code:

```
var LinkedList = function(e){

  var that = {}, first, last;

  that.push = function(value){
    var node = new Node(value);
    if(first == null){
      first = last = node;
    }else{
      last.next = node;
      last = node;
    }
  };

  that.pop = function(){
    var value = first;
    first = first.next;
    return value;
  };

  that.remove = function(index) {
    var i = 0;
    var current = first, previous;
    if(index === 0){
      //handle special case - first node
      first = current.next;
    }else{
      while(i++ < index){
        //set previous to first node
        previous = current;
        //set current to the next one
        current = current.next
      }
      //skip to the next node
      previous.next = current.next;
    }
    return current.value;
  };

  var Node = function(value){
    this.value = value;
    var next = {};
  };

  return that;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var that = {}, first, last;
```

is similar to

```
var that = {};
var first;
var last;
```

We are initializing `that` with an empty object, whereas `first` and `last` are uninitialized. So they will have the default value `undefined`.

JavaScript assigns values to the variables declared in a single statement from left to right. So, the following

```
var that = {}, first, last = that;
console.log(that, first, last);
```

will print

```
{} undefined {}
```

where as

```
var that = last, first, last = 1;
console.log(that, first, last);
```

would print

```
undefined undefined 1
```

Because, by the time `that` is assigned `last`, the value of `last` is not defined yet. So, it will be `undefined`. That is why `that` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a shorthand way to create multiple variables. It might be more clear if written as:

```
var that = {}, 
    first, 
    last;
```

And is equivalent to:

```
var that = {};
var first;
var last;
```